# Ordenação de dados com php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, classificação, estrutura-de-dados

Preciso ordenar um array por um campo específico "ordem", onde dentro desse array eu tenho objetos banners com os campo id, ordem, nome e img. preciso ordenar este array pela ordem. o banner de ordem 0 precisa vir em primeiro, 1 em segundo e assim por diante.

Comment: Tem exemplo desse array? Se sim coloque na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método sortBy de uma Collection, para isso, crie um objeto Collection a partir do array e ordene:

```
$collection = collect($array)->sortBy('ordem');
```

Espero que ajude.